# Match multiple words with regex if they do not contain a number

Tags: python, regex

This question might be dumb, I'm new to regex and I am a bit stuck.

I have multiple strings, with numbers and words in them. I want to match only the words, if they do not contain an integer.

`12 This Is A Test 9eifEf 12`

From that, I would like to match `This Is A Test`.

`11 Stack 21deEh 12`

From that, I would like to match `Stack`.

Using RegExr, I came up with the expression `.[a-z]`, which looked like it worked, but it matched a maximum of 2 letters at a time, and not the spaces.

Sorry for the code request. I do not need anything more than the pattern. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Split the string and check if all the characters are letters (`[x for x in s.split() if x.isalpha()]`). Or is the requirement more specific?

Comment: Did you understand why your regex is false?
The `.` will match any character (which is not what you want), the `[a-Z]` will only match one lowercase letter, and you forgot `\b` word delimiters. See Willem's post for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+\b
```

Here:

- `\b` is a word boundary such that we do not match words that begin with digits;
- `[A-Za-z]` is a character group that contains all upper and lower letters; and
- `+` means "*one or more*".

If you want to return the string then, you can - as @James says - use `' '.join(..)`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> rgx=re.compile(r'\b[A-Za-z]+\b')
>>> text='12 This Is A Test 9eifEf 12'
>>> rgx.findall(text)
['This', 'Is', 'A', 'Test']
>>> ' '.join(rgx.findall(text))
'This Is A Test'
```

Comment: Also: `' '.join(...)` to return the combined string.

Comment: @James: thanks. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex, use `str.isalpha` to filter out digits out of splitted words:

```
s = "12 This Is A Test 9eifEf 12"

print(" ".join([x for x in s.split() if x.isalpha()]))
```

gives:

```
This Is A Test
```

this won't preserve multiple spaces, though. To do it, just do:

```
print(" ".join([x for x in s.split(" ") if not x or x.isalpha()]))
```

Comment: @ChrisRands: thanks for the edit, but the square brackets were intentional. It's faster with that, as surprising as it may seem.